# creating instruction screen in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I often time see in an iOS apps when you first launch the app there will be a one time instruction with arrows and such to show a first time user guide. It's usually a black transparant colored screen with arrows. I was trying to find a few app that does this, but I couldn't. Was wondering if someone knew the terms for these and how to create it?

Comment: Too broad of a question.

Comment: Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UIView` and place it above the view you're wishing to guide the user through. Set up the `UIView` as a `IBOutlet` in your classes header file, set the background to black and set the alpha to 0.3 or something similar (test to see how it looks).

In header:

```
IBOutlet UIView *overlayView;
```

In main:

```
overlayView.alpha = 0.3f;
```

You may want to make sure that the overlay shows the first time the users opens the app or maybe store a value in a database for when the user dismisses the screen so that you don't show it again. To do this you can hide the `UIView` or simply set the alpha to 0.

Then simply add images or annotations to the `UIView`. As "bentford" said it's quite broad but this should get you on your way. You can also use multiple `UIView`'s or even transformations to animate the screens.

Comment: Instead of a database, just put a first started flag in the mainBundle

Comment: You could. Depends if you have a database already or not I suppose.

Comment: Point is you wouldn't by default, and setting one up to store a flag... is pretty much the definition of overkill. Your mainBundle is designed to store persistent app state like this.

Comment: doh, typo, not mainBundle, I mean `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: e.g. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:appFirstStartOfVersionKey]`

Comment: I did wonder ;) Yea you could do that. I've never used it but I probably will from now.

Answer (score 0):

I use Skitch.  You can find it in the Mac App Store.

Skitch can take the screenshot in the simulator and overlay the arrows and notes. Then when you launch the app, you show the image created with Skitch in a UIImageView on top of the actual view.  Then just hide the UIImageView.